# What are the tradeoffs in the choice of n_jobs?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

This question is related to choice of `n_jobs` in functions like GridSearchCV etc.

We understand that with `n_jobs=-1` computation will be dispatched on all the CPUs of the computer. There are other implications if we use a number less than -1 or greater than or equal to 1.

My doubt is why it should be a choice at all? Should it not be always -1? In what situation we will use a setting other than -1?

Comment: Maybe you need some CPUs for other stuff. Maybe your internal algorithm is already using parallel-processing and additional (outer) parallelization will only slow things down. And then there is also a memory-overhead when using this kind  of parallelization like used in GridSearchCV. Additionally, the detected number might not be optimal (hyper-threading and co. and many other cases)

Answer (score 0):

Because when you submit the computation as a job to some cluster manager, e.g. SGE, you typically allocate a given number of CPUs. Consuming more would make your colleagues unhappy.